# DataGridView, Get the value of the first column of the selected row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm wondering what would be the most efficient way to get the value of the first column in an DataGridView row.

Currently, I'm using this code:

```
List<string> SelectedRows = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgv.SelectedRows)
{
    SelectedRows.Add(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}

int index = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedRows[0]);
```

This works fine; however, is there a more efficient option to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Most efficient" is often subjective. I don't know that the following code is faster or shorter than what you've already got, but it's the method I prefer to use.

If you're trying to get a list of all values from a particular column, try this:

```
var results = dataGridView1.SelectedRows
                           .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.Cells[0].Value));
```

If you only allow one selected row at a time, and you want to convert a particular cell, try this:

```
var index = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

I did some performance testing with the code given in the answers. The average time for each method over 1.000.000 times:

My original code:

```
List<string> SelectedRows = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgv.SelectedRows)
{
    SelectedRows.Add(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}

int index = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedRows[0]);
```

Time = 0,0159 ms

```
var results = dataGridView1.SelectedRows
                           .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.Cells[0].Value));
```

Time = 0,0152 ms

```
var index = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
```

When single-select only: 0,0013438 ms

```
List<string> SelectedRows = new List<string>();
for (int count = 0; count < dgv.SelectedRows.Count; count++)
{
    SelectedRows.Add(dgv.SelectedRows[count].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
int index = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedRows[0]);
```

Time = 0,0057 ms

Comment: Even when my answer got better results you marked the other guy's answer as the answer :( Not fair

Comment: My apologies, sadly I can't select multiple answers. Your help is much appreciated though :)

Comment: Oh no no buddy do not apologize, was just kidding :P

Comment: Hi if you want improve the performance of for loop. don't every time count the row of the datagridview. only first time get the count the row and assign that to for loop like this.                                                                                                 *                                                                                                                      int rowCount=dgv.SelectedRows.Count                                                           
for (int count = 0; count <rowCount; count++)

Answer (score 2):

Copying this from Patrick Smacchia's [Blog](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances/):

`The fact that for is more efficient than foreach results from the fact that foreach is using an enumerator object behind the scene.`

I prefer using `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop, `for` loop is preferably faster than `foreach` loop when you do not have to do something to each element, and can solve your problem by just using the index as follows:

```
List<string> SelectedRows = new List<string>();
for (int count = 0; count < dgv.SelectedRows.Count; count++)
{
    SelectedRows.Add(dgv.SelectedRows[count].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
int index = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedRows[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the first column of the selected row, in the dataGridView's contentClick we can put this code, and that value can be saved in id variable

```
  private void datagridview1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {

             var id = Convert.ToInt32(datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
            }
```

Comment: Hey there. Welcome here. What about explaining the code with words? We prefer answers that do not only contain few lines of code. There's a edit button below your answer. Feel free to edit this!